# Can't login into Xamarin account Visual Studio 2015 Communitiy

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

With a *FRESH* installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and the free version of Xamarin (with brand new activated account) i got this error when i try to login within VS:

```
 System.Exception: Could not load machine data:
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>d__88.MoveNext()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass13.<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>b__12(Task t)
```

The dialog says to contact support, but as i am not with a business edition, i have no access to the support.
Anyone had this problem, or an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Isn't Visual Studio for Xamarin a business-only feature?

Comment: No, there is a "starter" version, which is free: https://xamarin.com/starter.

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous donwvoter for the vote - it is helping everyone!

Answer (score 5):

### Solve by Updating

Your question is a bit old (hopefully you managed to get it working already!), but as it was never *answered* I wanted to provide some information on this error for reference:

1. **The error message by itself is not enough to diagnose the cause of the problem.** Essentially the error only provides the information that the machine data was unreadable for some reason; but there are several possible causes of the issue. Source: [Bug 17613, Comment 37](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17613#c37).
2. **At least one common cause was patched in Xamarin.Android 5.1.8.0**. This was reported in the [Xamarin release blog](https://releases.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-hotfix-for-stable-channel-to-address-could-not-load-machine-data-error/). However consistent with item #1 this fix did not address every possible scenario that could cause the error to occur.
3. **Updating to a post-//Build 2016 version of Xamarin should fix remaining causes of this error for most users**. This is because of the licensing change to [allow for MSDN support](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/license/#Introduction), which should not hit this error, because the licensing doesn't work the same way. Generally it is recommended to stay up to date with at least the [latest stable version of Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/current/).

### If this error is seen *after* updating to a recent release of Xamarin

1. Try the steps in this FAQ article to [resync your Xamarin license](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/legacy-licenses/resync-licenses/). Legacy license holders should follow all the steps in the guide, but MSDN license holders only need to clean out / delete any old licenses if they still exist on their machine (usually only if they had Xamarin  licenses before //Build 2016).
2. If that fails, please refer to the [Support Options Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/support-options/) for further assistance.

**Final Note**: The information provided here applies to the specific error message `Could not load machine data:` followed by no other error messages on the same line, just the stacktrace underneath. If you see an error like `Could not load machine data: (SomeMessageHere)`, then that message after the colon could indicate a more specific problem, so be sure to mention the full error message if updating doesn't help / you request further support on the issue.